# How to create volumetric/smoke material in blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine, materials, volumetrics

I would like to create a hologram of sci-fi ship. I created materials in blender render and hoped, that they will be easily used in game engine too (my mistake).

And I have been unable to create the effect I want - volumetric/smoke effect (image bellow)[image]

This is what I have been able to come up with in game engine so far. (image bellow)[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Hologram effect like requested above with visible node shader]

The trick: Set the object to 'shade smooth' and use the surface normal.
It doesn't work everywhere (such as the left edge of the object, but it works well enough in a lot of cases.
I use this trick quite often, for things like fire, which you can do with a single distorted sphere and some UV-scroll.

Note that this requires GLSL, and uses a node material.

If you mix it with a cloud texture you can make smoke/clouds:
[image: An Orange cloud]

The blend for the cloud can be downloaded from [blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?342799-Fluffballs)

Comment: Nice one, cool technique